# Tycho: How to copy p2 update site to a Tomcat server

Tags: maven, tycho

Currently, I am using a Tycho build to generate my product installations/zips and p2 update site repository locally. I would like to copy only the p2 update site to a tomcat server. 
Any idea how to do this with the latest Tycho version?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Maven Antrun plugin and embed an upload script. The maven environment variables allow you to produce a relative path, so this will work independent of the location.